# An example of two functions whose limits don't exist at a but the limit of their product does

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Show by example that the $\lim \limits_{x \to a} [f(x) \cdot g(x)]$ may exist even though neither $\lim \limits_{x \to a} [f(x)]$ nor $\lim \limits_{x \to a} [g(x)]$ exist.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Maybe you should put your answer in your question post and put the tag: solution verification. In case you want us to review your solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an example from the old book for this question. Take for example

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$} \\
1 & \text{if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$} \\
0 & \text{if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$}
\end{cases}$$
and note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ does not exist but since that $f(x)g(x)$ is constant function, so the $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ there exists.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the limit at $0$ for the functions:

$$f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb R_{\ge 0}} = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ for } x \ge 0\\0 &\text{ for } x < 0\end{cases}, \quad g(x) = 1-f(x)$$

then both $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ do not exist.

However $f(x)g(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)g(x) = 0$.

Alternatively, if $a = \pm \infty$, the limits of $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ do not exist at $a$.

However $\tan x \cot x \equiv 1$ almost everywhere, so the limit of their product is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example is $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x-a})$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$: then neither $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist, but clearly $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. If you want an example for $x\to (\pm)\infty$, just take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and again $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$.